# How mongodb $each modifier works with "complex" objects

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Imagine we have the following document:

```
{"_id": 1, "field": "name", "array": [{name: "foo", "last": "bar"}]}
```

I have a unique index on the property `last`

How MongoDB `$each` modifier works with this kind of "complex" object if I want to try inserting the following object into the field `array`:

```
 {name: "foo", "last": "bar"} //Has the same data
```

Somehow, MongoDB is trying to insert and I'm facing a DupException.

The code below is what I have so far:

```
    final BasicUpdate basicUpdate = new BasicUpdate(new Document()
            .append("$addToSet", new Document("array", new Document("$each", objects /*with the "complex" objects*/)))
            .append("$setOnInsert", new Document()
                    .append("fieldone", "dataone")
                    .append("fieldtwo", "datatwo")
            .append("$set", new Document()
                    .append("updatedAt", Instant.now())
                    .append("fieldone", "anotherdataone")
                    .append("fieldtwo", "anotherdatatwo"))
    ));

    try {
        result = mongoTemplate.upsert(query, basicUpdate, Object.class);
    } catch(DuplicateKeyException e) {
    }
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#mongodb-update-up.-each) the "push/inserting" will occur if only if the element doesn't exist.

Btw, I'm using the `$each` along with the `$addToSet` operator.

So, It seems MongoDB is not able to know the uniqueness of this kind of objects, or maybe I'm missing something :-)

Comment: How do you try to update the document? Please show us the statement.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit see the updated question

Comment: Actually it does not help at all. Tell us the content of `objects /*with the "complex" objects*/` Also the rest of the update statement does not match the sample data. How did you create the index?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a unique index then uniqueness applies to the document, not to the array.

See this simple example:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ "array.last": 1 }, { unique: true }) 
db.collection.insertOne({ field: "name", array: [{ name: "foo", last: "bar" }] })
db.collection.insertOne({ field: "name2", array: [{ name: "foo2", last: "bar" }] })

WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 11000,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: so.collection index: array.last_1 dup key: { array.last: \"bar\" }",
    "op" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60c05ef7136ecd015ea689c5"),
        "field" : "name2",
        "array" : [
            {
                "name" : "foo2",
                "last" : "bar"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

The index enforces you to have only one document having the element `array.last: "bar"`.

The array itself is not affected by the index, you can insert this one (but only once, of course):

```
db.collection.insertOne({
   field: "name", array: [
      { name: "foo", last: "bar2" },
      { name: "foo", last: "bar2" }
   ]
})
```